# How to align Series columns and Dataframe columns into the same row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns, series

I am trying to align my results for column 'Column5' to align in the same row as all the other columns after converting a pandas series to a dataframe. This is the default behaviour when using the code below. I need this because the other columns are not recognised as columns except Column5. I looked all over but cannot find help on this:

```
combinedAllExits = pd.DataFrame(combinedAllExits, columns=['Column5'])

                                                        Column5
Column1                Column2   Column3 Column4          
1 - PAID               201208    8       August         65.0
                       201209    9       September      47.0
                       201210    10      October        54.0
                       201211    11      November       48.0
                       201212    12      December       20.0
                       201301    1       January        64.0
                       201302    2       February       43.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
print s
Column1   Column2  Column3  Column4  
1 - PAID  201208   8        August       65.0
          201209   9        September    47.0
          201210   10       October      54.0
          201211   11       November     48.0
          201212   12       December     20.0
          201301   1        January      64.0
          201302   2        February     43.0
Name: Column5, dtype: float64

print s.reset_index()
    Column1  Column2  Column3    Column4  Column5
0  1 - PAID   201208        8     August     65.0
1  1 - PAID   201209        9  September     47.0
2  1 - PAID   201210       10    October     54.0
3  1 - PAID   201211       11   November     48.0
4  1 - PAID   201212       12   December     20.0
5  1 - PAID   201301        1    January     64.0
6  1 - PAID   201302        2   February     43.0
```

It is same as:

```
print pd.DataFrame(s, columns=['Column5']).reset_index()
    Column1  Column2  Column3    Column4  Column5
0  1 - PAID   201208        8     August     65.0
1  1 - PAID   201209        9  September     47.0
2  1 - PAID   201210       10    October     54.0
3  1 - PAID   201211       11   November     48.0
4  1 - PAID   201212       12   December     20.0
5  1 - PAID   201301        1    January     64.0
6  1 - PAID   201302        2   February     43.0
```

Comment: I should have tried that, thanks very much @jezrael much appreciated.